Pyspark script does not save iceberg file
Trying to write a Pyspark script that reads a parquet file and save it in iceberg format. (later on it is supposed to read the newly created iceberg file and create an iceberg table on it)
Issue is that the script read the parquet data but then silently quits without saving any iceberg file. Already confirmed that spark_dataframe_parq contains expected data.
I suspect that either my spark initialization is missing some option OR that I am using the write method incorrectly. Please let me know on what am I overlooking here.
Thanks
Script
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
    
import sys

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.4_2.12:1.3.0')
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.icebergcat", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
    .getOrCreate()
)
.......
.......

# read parquet file
spark_dataframe_parq = spark.read.parquet(parquet_file_path)
print ("Saving to iceberg table : ", iceberg_table_path)
spark_dataframe_parq.write.mode(saveMode="overwrite").format("iceberg").option("path",iceberg_table_path)
print ("Saved...") 

Output
Kernel: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
Python version: 3.9.6 (default, Mar 29 2024, 10:51:09)
[Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)]
Spark version: 3.5.1
PySpark version: 3.5.1
PySpark Version : 3.5.1
.......
.......

Saving to iceberg table : output/data_iceberg_table
Saved...

